# https taking long to run on production mode

Tags: java, https

So i hit a https request to other server.I have reduced its time by adding set Timeout property which timeouts after 5 seconds in case response does not come from server.Problem is setup is working fine on dev mode but in production mode timeout do  not work and it takes 4-5 minutes to get response from server.

USE CASE:
i am not sending username and password while connecting to server as i need to catch the exception and give appropriate message to user.I am using XmlRpcClientConfigImpl client and TrustManager and SSLContext of java.net for handshaking.

HAve done some logging also in which code inside exception runs after 4-5 mins

Refered from [setTimeout using xmlprc](https://dzone.com/articles/apache-xml-rpc-how-configure)

I am using jetty as server
Here is some code as i can not share much of it

```
connected =true;
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(ServerVO.getHost(), ServerVO.getPort(), ServerVO.getUserName(), ServerVO.getPassword(), isHTTP);
            int defaultConnTimeOut = SomeCass.getConnectionTimeOut();
            int defaultReplyTimeOut = SomeCass.getReplyTimeOut();

            SomeCass.setConnectionTimeOut(2000);
            SomeCass.setReplyTimeOut(5000);

            try {
                logger.info("fetching versionnnnnnnn-----------------");
            SomeCass.version();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info("fetching versionnnnnnnn-------exceptionnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn----------");
                connected = Boolean.FALSE;
            }

            finally {
                SomeCass.setConnectionTimeOut(defaultConnTimeOut);
                SomeCass.setReplyTimeOut(defaultReplyTimeOut);
            }
```

code for timeout

```
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
XmlRpcClient client = new XmlRpcClient();
config.setServerURL(new URL(serverURL));
config.setConnectionTimeout(xmlrpcConnTimeout);
config.setReplyTimeout(xmlrpcReplyTimeOut);
client.setConfig(config);
```

//setting host username everything in config

Code for handshake on Proxy class consturctor

```
  this.address = address;
            this.port = port;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;
            this.url = url;
            if(!this.isHTTP) {
                TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                        // Trust always
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                            String authType) {
                        // Trust always
                    }
                } };
                // Install the all-trusting trust manager
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                // Create empty HostnameVerifier
                HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
            }
```

Comment: Are you using the same server for the DEV? What server are you using, how did you set the timeout ? In dev, you always got a timeout if this takes 5min to respond I guess. Can you please include a bit more of details ? This might be a problem for another stack exchange community but we'll see.

Comment: hey alex i have mentioned a link at end of my question and basically we are making an installer that runs on localhost.we are using jetty

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this

Added this property to XMLRPCclient

```
client.setTransportFactory(new XmlRpcCommonsTransportFactory(client));
```

It creates a new instance for every request

https still taking 5 sec extra than http but i guess it is the expected behavior as https is generaly slower than http.Still if anyone can suggest how to reduce this time further would be a great help